# rails json filter ":only"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, filter

I did the following query on my model:

```
output = user.interests.includes([:culture, :sports])
```

This gives me all the "interests" with all the "culture" and "sports" entries of the user.
I'd like to forward only the id column for "interests", "culture" and "sports" to the client as json.

I tried doing it this way:

```
output.to_json(:include => [:culture, :sports], :only => ['id'])
```

When doing it that way it only shows the IDs of the interests but still includes every column of "culture" and "sports". What do I have to add to restrict "culture" and "sports" also to only the IDs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add options for each of the includes by using a separate hash, e.g:

```
output.to_json(:include => { :culture => { :only => :id }, :sports => { :only => :id } }, :only => ['id'])
```

Comment: thanks! seems to work partially. With this I get the IDs of interests and culture. But sports completely disapears in the result. I can't spot a syntax error. Do you know what could be the problem in this case?

Comment: My mistake, you need to use a hash instead of an array for the includes. Updated the answer.